# Reorder geom_path lines to match factor level order

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot the sum of animal counts ("Sum") across three months for three projects as `geom_point`s connected by `geom_path`s.

I have specified the order of the x axis by manually ordering the "Month" factor's levels.

How do I re-order the `geom_path` to follow the new order of the x axis and smoothly connect the points?

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame("Project" = c("Cass River", "Cass River", "Cass River", "Godley River", "Godley River", "Godley River", "Tasman River", "Tasman River", "Tasman River"), 
                 "Month" = c("2019_Apr", "2019_Mar", "2019_May","2019_Mar", "2019_Apr", "2019_May", "2019_Mar", "2019_Apr", "2019_May"), 
                 "Sum" = as.integer(c("66", "3", "42", "0", "23", "7", "18", "70", "12")))

#Set the order of the months
df <- df %>% mutate(Month = factor(Month, levels = c("2019_Mar", "2019_Apr", "2019_May")))

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Month, y = Sum, group = Project)) +
     geom_point(aes(color = Project))+
     geom_path(aes(color = Project))+
     theme_classic() +
     theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) +
     xlab("\nDate") + 
     ylab("Total number of hedgehogs")
```

[image: Here is my current output]

Comment: I suspect you want `geom_line` instead of `geom_path`. Also, consider converting `df$Sum` to integer / numeric.

Comment: Yes, that's done it, thank you! I will edit the question as `df$Sum` is an integer in my original data.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure your expected outcome, and why you use `geom_path`. Also, you original data and code cannot reproduce the graph in OP on my machine.

It may be helpful we use a numeric variable for `x` axis. I used `zoo::as.yearmon()`. As suggested by @Z.Lin, I also replaced `geom_path` with `geom_line`. Let me know if this is not helpful and I will delete it.

```
library(zoo)
df$Month <- as.yearmon(str_replace(df$Month, "_", "-"), "%Y-%B")

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Month, y = Sum, color = Project)) +
  geom_point()+
  geom_line() + 
#  geom_path(aes(color = Project))+
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) +
  xlab("\nDate") + 
  ylab("Total number of hedgehogs")
```

[image]

Comment: This is helpful, thanks. It wasn't necessary for me to change to a year month format but the `geom_line` change did the trick. I had originally not had luck with `geom_line` so used `geom_path` although I admit I don't know when to use one or the other. Thanks!